# Can you run an inner join command on multiple tables with different primary keys?

Tags: mysql, sql

If I want to select rows from 3 different tables in SQL, do I need to have at least 1 table that relates to both?

Here is my example:

I have 3 tables - Table A, Table B and Table C

Table B has a primary key that relates to both Table A and C and I can relate to it easily using something like this.

**In the coding examples, Table A = employee, Table B = works_with, Table C = client**

```
SELECT employee.fname, employee.lname, client.client_name, works_with.total_sales
FROM works_with INNER JOIN client ON works_with.client_id = client.client_id 
INNER JOIN employee ON works_with.emp_id = employee.emp_id;
```

So my  above query works for obvious reasons. But because I am learning MySQL I am trying to break stuff and test things to see what the limits are.

So this is my question - Is there a way to write a query like below. The example fails but am curious if its possible.

```
SELECT employee.fname, employee.lname, client.client_name, works_with.total_sales
    FROM employee INNER JOIN employee ON employee.emp_id = works_with.client_id FROM
    works_with INNER JOIN client ON works_with.emp_id = = client.client_id;
```

Comment: Huh?  You have a working query.  You then have a non-working query (with two `FROM` clauses).  I have no idea what you are trying to do.

Comment: Is it possible to construct a query that won't work? QED.

Comment: For further help, see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query?__=1753130441

Answer (score 0):

Your second query:

```
SELECT employee.fname, employee.lname, client.client_name, works_with.total_sales
FROM employee INNER JOIN
     employee
     ON employee.emp_id = works_with.client_id
FROM works_with INNER JOIN
     client
     ON works_with.emp_id = client.client_id;
```

This just makes no sense.  It has two `FROM` clauses.  That is not syntactically valid.  It has a self-join on `employee`, which is unnecessary for the logic you want.  It refers to `works_with` before it is defined in the `FROM` clause.  No sense at all.

I would suggest that you write your first query with table aliases:

```
SELECT e.fname, e.lname, c.client_name, ww.total_sales
FROM works_with ww INNER JOIN
     client c
     ON ww.client_id = c.client_id INNER JOIN
     employee e
     ON ww.emp_id = e.emp_id;
```